# Sets and pointwise convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions which converge pointwise to $f$ in $X\ne\emptyset$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be some constant. We define
$$A_m^{\epsilon}=\{x : \text{sup}_{n\ge m}|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\}.$$ I have proved that $A_{m}^{\epsilon}\supset A_{m+1}^{\epsilon}$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. How can I show that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} A_m^{\epsilon}=\emptyset.$$
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By showing that $\limsup A_m^{\epsilon}=\varnothing$.

---

Then based on $\liminf A_m^{\epsilon}\subseteq\limsup A_m^{\epsilon}$ we are allowed to conclude that $$\liminf A_m^{\epsilon}=\varnothing=\limsup A_m^{\epsilon}$$

That allows us to conclude that $\lim A_m^{\epsilon}$ is well defined and takes value $\varnothing$.

It comes to proving that for every $x$ then is an integer $m_x$ such that $m\geq m_x$ implies that $x\notin A_m^{\epsilon}$.

That means that the set $\{m\mid x\in A_m^{\epsilon}\}$ is finite hence $x\notin\limsup A_m^{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 1):

Every $x\in X$ belongs to only finitely many $A^c_m.$ If not, then for some $x\in X$ we have $\forall m \;\exists n\geq m\;(|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon /2),$ contradictory to $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x).$